# Scapy - Function 'sr1()' doesn't Return Response-Packet

Tags: python, windows, networking, scapy, icmp

Hello guys I have a problem with Scapy in Python 3 on Windows 10. I tried to send a Ping (ICMP) request to my default-gateway. This is the packet command:

```
p = IP(dst='10.0.0.138')/ICMP(type='echo-request')/Raw('Hello')
```

But after I write `r = sr1(ping)` the program is stuck on this output:

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
```

I used Wireshark to check the packets and I saw the both packets: Request and response. What do I do wrong? This has been working for me for whole life until now.

Edit: I am using the Scapy-Shell right now.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved, I just needed to give networks privileges to the Python Interpreter. Thanks for all your help.